# Django : Redirect after post doesn't work

Tags: django

After Create moneylog, I want to got back to moneybook_detail, so I made a **moneylog/view.py**:

```
 class moneylog_create(CreateView):
    form_class = forms.CreateMoneylogForm
    template_name = "moneylogs/create.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        moneylog = form.save()
        moneybook = moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(
            pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
        form.instance.moneybook = moneybook
        moneylog.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(reverse("moneybooks:detail", kwargs={'pk': moneybook.pk}))
```

and this is **moneybook/urls.py**

```
app_name = "moneybooks"

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/", views.moneybook_create.as_view(), name="create"),
    path("update/<int:pk>/",
         views.moneybook_update.as_view(), name="update"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.moneybook_detail, name="detail")
]
```

**moneylogs/urls.py**

```
app_name = "moneylogs"

urlpatterns = [
    path("create/<int:pk>/", views.moneylog_create.as_view(), name="create"),
    path("update/<int:pk>/", views.moneylog_update.as_view(), name="update")
]
```

here is my **detail.html**

```
<a style="display:scroll;position:fixed;bottom:50px;right:30px;" href="{% url 'moneylogs:create' pk %}">
    <div class="rounded-full h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center bg-red-400 text-bold font-bold text-white">+</div>
</a>
```

here is my **moneylogs/forms.py**

```
class CreateMoneylogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Moneylog
        fields = (
            "pay_day",
            "payer",
            "dutch_payer",
            "price",
            "category",
            "memo",
        )
        widgets = {
            "payer": forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"style": "width: 100 %"}),
            "dutch_payer": forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            "memo": forms.Textarea(attrs={"rows": 3})
        }

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        moneylog = super().save(commit=False)
        return moneylog
```

and moneylog_form.html

```
<form method="POST" class="w-full" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span> 
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

        <div class="input {% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="w-1/4">
                    {{form.name.label}} 
                </div>
                <div class="w-3/4 border-b my-2 py-3">
                    {{form.name}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if form.name.errors %}
                {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                    <span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span> 
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>


        <div class="input {% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="w-1/4">
                    {{form.companion.label}} 
                </div>
                <div class="w-3/4 flex inline border-b my-2 py-3">
                    <div class="w-3/4">
                        {{form.companion}}
                    </div>
                    <div class= "w-1/4 flex justify-center ">
                        <a href="{% url 'tempfriends:create' %}"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if form.companion.errors %}
                {% for error in form.companion.errors %}
                    ><span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>


        <div class="input {% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="w-1/4">
                    {{form.country.label}} 
                </div>
                <div class="w-3/4 border-b my-2 py-3">
                    {{form.country}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if form.country.errors %}
                {% for error in form.country.errors %}
                    <span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span> 
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>


        <div class="input {% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="w-1/4">
                    {{form.location.label}} 
                </div>
                <div class="w-3/4 border-b my-2 py-3">
                    {{form.location}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if form.location.errors %}
                {% for error in form.location.errors %}
                    <span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span> 
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>


        <div class="input {% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="w-1/4">
                    {{form.start_date.label}} 
                </div>
                <div class="w-3/4 border-b my-2 py-3">
                    {{form.start_date}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if form.start_date.errors %}
                {% for error in form.start_date.errors %}
                    <span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span> 
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>


        <div class="input {% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="w-1/4">
                    {{form.end_date.label}} 
                </div>
                <div class="w-3/4 border-b my-2 py-3">
                    {{form.end_date}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if form.end_date.errors %}
                {% for error in form.end_date.errors %}
                    <span class="text-red-700 font-medium text-sm">{{error}}</span> 
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>


    <button class="px-2 py-1 rounded bg-red-500 text-white">{{cta}}</button>
</form>
```

there is no page redirect. no move, it print just log

> "POST /moneylogs/create/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5275

How can I return to moneybook_detail after create moneylog?? why my redirect doesn't work?

Comment: This probably means that your form is not valid. Are you displaying your form errors in your "moneylogs/create.html" template?

Comment: yes i display my form errors in my template but there is no error. i updated my forms too. if you dont mind, could you check it plz?

Comment: I'm sure the for isn't valid, otherwise it would redirect. Add `{{ form.errors }}` somewhere in your template (to print **all the errors**) there's probably something you're missing.

Comment: i guess that is good approach... but i'm not sure... either for or form isn't valid...

Comment: Note that the template you're showing is for the wrong form, the fields are named differently. Also `field` isn't defined in `{% if field.errors %}has_error{% endif %}`

Comment: thanks for the reply. However, Although i changed field.errors to form.(field name).errors , there is no change. and I can't find why the form is wrong.

Comment: Did you add `{{ form.errors }}` somewhere to show **all the errors in your form**? Alternatively, add the `form_invalid(self, form)` method in your view (that just calls `super()`) and set a breakpoint there to inspect your form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic `CreateView` has two possible return paths when receiving a `POST` request:

- `form_valid()` which in your case redirects. This is a HTTP status 302.
- `form_invalid()` which renders the template again with the bound form in its context, in order to display the errors. This is a HTTP status 200.

Since your request returns status 200, we can conclude that the view went into the `form_invalid()` method, meaning your form has errors. It seems you're rendering the various field errors (although the template you're showing is for the wrong form, I assume this is a copy & paste error) but the easiest to debug is add `{{ form.errors }}` at the top of your template to display **all errors**. Or set a breakpoint in your `form_invalid()` method (override it to `return super().form_invalid(form)`).

Comment: Thanks for your kindly answer. {{form.errors}} help me finding a type error (payday -> pay_day) and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

either change the `app_name` or change the `href` in `details.html`. Because in one place you mentioned `moneylogs` and in another place, you mentioned `moneybooks`.

Comment: I understand what you say, but moneylog and moneybook is independent so I think that detail.html url 'moneylogs:create' pk is right.